# DBMS_DEBUG.GET_INDEXES or other ways how to get indexes of an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY indexed by VARCHAR2 from debugged session

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

Does anyone know how to programmatically get VARCHAR2 indexes of an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY indexed by VARCHAR2 from debugged session? DBMS_DEBUG.GET_INDEXES works fine for numeric index type but I want to be able to get VARCHAR2 indexes too.